# Packaging Software Ideas

Tags: node.js, software-distribution, packing

We have a migration tool to migrate the customers data between different applications. I am looking for ideas to make it very easy for the customer to use this tool. Right now they invoke shell scripts with some options and get the data dump, but I want to make this even more easier for the end customer. Tool is written in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

[pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) could be what you're looking for.

From the package description:

> This command line interface enables you to package your Node.js
>   project into an executable that can be run even on devices without
>   Node.js installed.
>
> **Use Cases**
>
> - Make a commercial version of your application without
>     sources
>
>   Make a demo/evaluation/trial version of your app without
>     sources
>
>   Instantly make executables for other platforms
>
>   (cross-compilation) Make some kind of self-extracting archive or
>
>   installer No need to install Node.js and npm to run the packaged
>     application No need to download hundreds of files via npm install to
>     deploy your application. Deploy it as a single file Put your assets
>     inside the executable to make it even more portable Test your app
>     against new Node.js version without installing it

Comment: Thanks but the caveat is that the user still should be able to supply arguments similar to the command line arguments through this tool.

Comment: @wowman are you looking for a command line tool? may be you can use this to create executable, but have a way of providing interactive configuration when the tool runs for the first time

Comment: I am looking for tool similar to command line tool. Thanks I will look into it and see ways to provide configuration to the tool